# python json skipping elements

Tags: python, json

Is is possible to skip elements while parsing json in python?

```
{
   "SUPDBL":{  
      "NONREF":{  
         ...
```

Can I go straight to the NONREF tab without needing to enter SUPDB?

The reason why I need this, I don`t know what text can be in the SUPDBL place so I would like to skip it.

Comment: Are you using a stream parser, or why are you asking…? If you simply `json.load` it into an object, then simply don't iterate over keys you don't want/like/need…!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to skip a specific JSON element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801197/python-how-to-skip-a-specific-json-element)

Comment: I think the simplest way to do that is loop through all key then check if key have NONREF or not. It's not take much time if your json data is small.

Answer (score 0):

You could also iterate through the keys of your dict:

```
import json

def return_nonref(json_string):
    d = json.loads(json_string)
    for key, value in d.items():
        if type(value) == dict:
            if 'NONREF' in value:
                return value['NONREF']
    return False


j = '''{ "SUPDBL": { "NONREF":{"a":1}}}'''

print(return_nonref(j))
```