# How To Capture Dynamic Keys In Nested Python Dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have written a script that grabs JSON data from a website and converts it to a Python Dictionary.
My goal here is to compare which product variation is the cheapest.

## Script

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.bulk.com/uk/b-vitamin-complex-tablets.html'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')


# Extract JSON from page
script = soup.find_all('script')[55].string.strip()[449:-80]

# Convert JSON string to Python Dictionary
data = json.loads(script)

# Product ID - (additionally grab label & product code)
print(data['attributes']['205']['options'][0]['products'])

# Product Price
print(data['optionPrices']['2955']['finalPrice'])

# Price Per Serving: used to compare cheapest product
print(data['pricePerServingsMap']['2955']['price_per_serving'])
```

## JSON Data

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "205": {
            "id": "205",
            "code": "bp_qty",
            "label": "QTY",
            "options": [{
                    "id": "17337",
                    "label": "180 Tablets",
                    "products": [
                        "2956"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "17355",
                    "label": "60 Tablets",
                    "products": [
                        "2955"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "position": "0"
        }
    },
    "template": "£<%- data.price %>",
    "currencyFormat": "£%s",
    "optionPrices": {
        "2955": {
            "baseOldPrice": {
                "amount": 6.99
            },
            "oldPrice": {
                "amount": 6.99
            },
            "basePrice": {
                "amount": 3.49
            },
            "finalPrice": {
                "amount": 3.49
            },
            "tierPrices": [],
            "msrpPrice": {
                "amount": 0
            }
        },
        "2956": {
            "baseOldPrice": {
                "amount": 14.99
            },
            "oldPrice": {
                "amount": 14.99
            },
            "basePrice": {
                "amount": 7.49
            },
            "finalPrice": {
                "amount": 7.49
            },
            "tierPrices": [],
            "msrpPrice": {
                "amount": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "priceFormat": {
        "pattern": "£%s",
        "precision": 2,
        "requiredPrecision": 2,
        "decimalSymbol": ".",
        "groupSymbol": ",",
        "groupLength": 3,
        "integerRequired": false
    },
    "prices": {
        "baseOldPrice": {
            "amount": 6.99
        },
        "oldPrice": {
            "amount": 6.99
        },
        "basePrice": {
            "amount": 3.49
        },
        "finalPrice": {
            "amount": 3.49
        }
    },
    "productId": "2954",
    "chooseText": "Select",
    "images": {
        "2955": {
            "main": "https://www.bulk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1500x1500/b/-/b-vitamin-complex-tablets_bpb-bvit-0000_main.jpg"
        },
        "2956": {
            "main": "https://www.bulk.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1500x1500/b/-/b-vitamin-complex-tablets_bpb-bvit-0000_main.jpg"
        }
    },
    "index": {
        "2955": {
            "205": "17355"
        },
        "2956": {
            "205": "17337"
        }
    },
    "channel": "website",
    "salesChannelCode": "bulkpowders",
    "sku": {
        "2955": "BPB-BVIT-TABS-0060",
        "2956": "BPB-BVIT-TABS-0180"
    },
    "disabledProducts": [],
    "oosProducts": [],
    "defaultFlavor": "",
    "pricePerServingsMap": {
        "2955": {
            "servings": 60,
            "price_per_serving": 0.06
        },
        "2956": {
            "servings": 180,
            "price_per_serving": 0.04
        }
    }
}
```

## Summary

Looking into the JSON script I see the **'attributes' key** contains a **dynamic nested key '205' which changes for every product on the website**. Within the nested key **'attributes > 205 > options'** we see the **product key pair as 2955**

Using the value of the products key pair being 2955, we can use this to grab the price using the **nested keys optionPrices > 2955 > finalPrice**

Again, we can used the same products key pair value 2955 to check for the **lowest value within the nested key pair pricePerServingsMap > 2955 > price_per_serving**

## Issue

My issues is that **I need a way to firstly capture the dynamic nested Key 205** and then **capture the products key pair 2955**

I can then use the captured dynamic nested key and key pair to navigate through the JSON structure to pick out the desired key pair price_per_serving to see which variant is the cheapest. Based on this I can backtrack and pull the price from the optionPrices nested keys.

I have checked a bunch of SO threads but was unable to find a suitable solution.
I found the following thread [Python - How to skip a specific JSON element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801197/python-how-to-skip-a-specific-json-element) but it simply produced errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated to demonstrate the process of identifying the lowest price variant based on the dynamic nature of the nested key and key pair values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand your intent, but you could look at

```
keys = list(data['attributes'].keys())
```

If there's only one key or you only need the first one take `key = keys[0]` or directly

```
key, *_ = data['attributes'].keys()
```

If there are more keys and you need them all, just iterate over them.

Comment: Thank you for your help.   I implemented the key capture process into my script and whilst it was a journey to get the final code working to achieve my end goal, it was a great learning curve.